# How does the less than operator work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following example.

```js
const x = false;
const y = "1";
const z = {};

console.log(x < y); // true
console.log(y < z); // true
console.log(x < z); // false
```

Since `x < y` and `y < z` both evaluate to `true`, I expected `x < z` to evaluate to `true` too because I thought `<` was [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). I was wrong. The `<` operator in JavaScript is not transitive. Hence, JavaScript values don't form an [ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). Not even a [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Anyway, I understand why `false < "1"` evaluates to `true`. The `false` is coerced to `0` and the `"1"` is coerced to `1`. What I don't understand is why `"1" < {}` evaluates to `true`, and why `false < {}` evaluates to `false`. Could you explain how these three expressions are evaluated, and how the `<` operator works in JavaScript?

Comment: [You can go straight to the spec.](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2021/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison)

Comment: Or e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than#description

Comment: hint: `"f" > "["`

Comment: _"The `false` is coerced to `0`_ - I think `false` is coerced to `"0"`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's coerced to `0` (ie: a [number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2023/#sec-tonumber))

Comment: This is not about < being transitive or not, it is all about type coercion, which is different in each of your examples.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `"1" < {}`, the object `{}` is not directly comparable, so JavaScript converts the object to a string using the default toString method.

[Image of conversion of {} to a string using toString Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGA8C.png)

So then comparing `"1" < {}.toString` which gives us true, since when comparing **"1" (U+0031)** comes before **"[" (U+005B)** alphabetically. Hence the output will be true.

Similarly, for the condition `false < {}`, while comparing an object with a boolean, the value for the object is NaN.
And hence `0 < NaN` which evaluates to **false**.

Comment: `({}).toString()` evaluates to `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Yes! you are right! The "1" is then compared to "[" which will return true.
Apologies for using "{"(corrected)

Comment: _'In the case of `"1" < "{}"`, the ...'_ - did you mean to write `"1" < {}`?

Comment: No while comparing the string with the an object the object is explicitly converted to string using toString Method which gets converted to [object,object] and hence "1" will be compared with "[". I have updated the answer thank you so much for the feedback.

Comment: `"{}"` is not the same as `{}.toString()`. You've said _"In the case of `"1" < "{}"`, the object `{}` ..."_, but there is no object in this comparison, just two strings `"{}"` & `"1"`, which isn't the case OP is asking about or is what you're actually describing. You're describing the case `y < z` ie, `"1" < {}`, not `"1" < "{}"`, so you really meant to say _"In the case of `"1" < {}`, ..."_

Comment: That was a typo mistake! Again thanks for the feedback. I appreciate it. 
Since I am a noobie here, I don't know how to answer firmly, Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The less than (<) operator returns true if the left operand is less than the right operand, and false otherwise.
Let's see examples of comparisons different types of values.
**String to string comparison**

```
"a" < "b"; // true
"a" < "a"; // false
"a" < "3"; // false
"\uD855\uDE51" < "\uFF3A"; // true
```

**String to number comparison**

```
"5" < 3; // false
"3" < 3; // false
"3" < 5; // true

"hello" < 5; // false
5 < "hello"; // false

"5" < 3n; // false
"3" < 5n; // true
```

**Comparing Boolean, null, undefined, NaN**

```
true < false; // false
false < true; // true

0 < true; // true
true < 1; // false

null < 0; // false
null < 1; // true

undefined < 3; // false
3 < undefined; // false

3 < NaN; // false
NaN < 3; // false
```

Also you must know!

- First, objects are converted to primitives by calling its @@toPrimitive (with "number" as hint), valueOf(), and toString() methods, in that order. The left operand is always coerced before the right one. Note that although @@toPrimitive is called with the "number" hint (meaning there's a slight preference for the object to become a number), the return value is not converted to a number, since strings are still specially handled.
- If both values are strings, they are compared as strings, based on the values of the UTF-16 code units (not Unicode code points) they contain.
- Otherwise JavaScript attempts to convert non-numeric types to numeric values:
  Boolean values true and false are converted to 1 and 0 respectively.
  null is converted to 0.
  undefined is converted to NaN.
  Strings are converted based on the values they contain, and are converted as NaN if they do not contain numeric values.
- If either value is NaN, the operator returns false.
- Otherwise the values are compared as numeric values. BigInt and number values can be compared together.

I hope, helped you. [I picked up answer from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than#description)

Answer (score 0):

JS tries to compare as numbers if any of the operands is numerish (boolean, number, date), if that fails (for example a string cannot be converted to a number or an operand is an object), it compares as strings.

For objects `toString()` method is used to convert an object to a string so if you provide a numeric string you can actually make an object comparable as a number, the `Numerish` example shows how you can change result of the previous comparing a boolean with an object.

Moreover an object can implement `valueOf()` method and return actual number.
In that case the comparison will be tried as numeric. The `Numeric` example shows that.

```js
const x = false;
const y = "1";
const z = {};

console.log(x < y); // true since 0 < 1 ('1' converted to 1)
console.log(y < z); // true since '1' < '[object Object]' ({} converted to a string)
console.log(x < z); // false since 'false' > '[object Object]' ({} cannot be converted to a number, so false converted to a string)

console.log('-1' > false); // false, since -1 < 0
console.log('-100' < '-200') // true, compared as strings

class Numerish{
  constructor(number){
    this.number = number;
  }
  toString(){
    return this.number;
  }
}

const num = new Numerish(1);

console.log(x < num); // true since toString() is used and 0 < '1'

class Numeric{
  constructor(number){
    this.number = number;
  }
  valueOf(){
    return this.number;
  }
}

const num2 = new Numeric(2);

console.log('11' > num2); // true compared as 11 > 2, though '11' > '2' is false

console.log(' ' > -1); // true since Number(' ') === 0 so 0 > -1
```